# CORS header set correctly in CURL but does not get set in when loading the page from a browser

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress, cors

I have a website which uses font-awesome and I want to use cloudfront as the CDN(my website runs on apache). I have enabled cors in the conf file for this site.

Here is the conf file for my site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin ajaydarez@gmail.com
    ServerName spotlessmommy.com
    ServerAlias www.spotlessmommy.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/spotlessmommy
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/spotlessmommy>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride ALL
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all

            Header set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding"
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"

            <FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">
                    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
            </FilesMatch>

    </Directory>
```

I am getting the right header passed through when I try it with curl -

```
E:\Software Files\curl>curl -I spotlessmommy.com/wp-content/themes/sociallyviral
/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 08 Sep 2015 01:04:00 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Fri, 29 May 2015 19:46:10 GMT
ETag: "228fc-5173dba530480"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 141564
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorizat
ion, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
Vary: User-Agent
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *


E:\Software Files\curl>curl -I spotlessmommy.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 08 Sep 2015 01:04:03 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11
X-Pingback: http://spotlessmommy.com/xmlrpc.php
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorizat
ion, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
Vary: User-Agent
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

But in the browser, I am still getting the cross-origin error for the font file. The site is www.spotlessmommy.com (if you load the site, you can see that the social media icons are just empty boxes)

```
Font from origin 'http://d13wghwkc7ps4m.cloudfront.net' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://spotlessmommy.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Any idea on what else I should try? Been struggling with this for the past 14 hours now :(

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the text of those images in the body of your question.

Comment: Updated my question with all the relevant info. Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. It was due to the delay in the CDN caching. After 24 hours, it works find now.